# Push notifications service for Ionic app

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

I'm developing a ionic app and I need to use push notifications. I found lot of informations but I'm not sure about few stuff.

1) For make it works I will need a notification server. And probably a node.js server with a DB for save a tokens or what is it. I found a `pushbots.com` or `Google Cloud Messaging` or `Apple Push Notification Service` for iOS. I don't know what I should use. But what I need is send a notification from iOS to Android. In this case I don't know if I can use `GCM` or I have to use APN. Should I use something else?

2) I found this plugin: [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and I think there isn't any solution else. There is not much informations about a notification services.

3) My purpose is sending an notification from one device to another like a message app.

I will be very glad for any information about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ionic, they have a service you can use - https://apps.ionic.io/landing/push

I haven't used it myself, but it seems perfect for what you are trying to achieve? It covers all device types.

Comment: ok, I will check it. It looks ionic will work also with GCM and APN.

Comment: I am assuming you sign up for each platforms push service and Ionic connects to it, you then use the Ionic API to send the notifications and it works with Google/Apple APIs to deliver. (at a total guess)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is [OneSignal](http://onesignal.com).

They offer free push service now.
The main features of this service is:

> - 15 Minute Setup.
> - Real Time Tracking.
> - Incredibly Scalable.
> - A/B Test Messages.
> - Segmentation Targeting.
> - Automatic Delivery.

They also provide us [RESTful API](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/server-api-overview) to push messages programmatically.

Visit their [Cordova/Ionic Docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap-sdk-overview) for more informations.

Comment: I will check it. Thanks